# Array of all valid neighbors in a 2d array

Tags: javascript

so I have a (randomly generated) 2d array of numbers like so:

```
[
     [0,1,2],
     [2,0,0],
     [1,0,2]
]
```

For each item in the array,  I need to be able to take its X and Y coords, and get information about it's neighbors,

for example x=0 and y=0 would refer by the two indexes to the upper left corner, so I would need to create an array of the top middle value, the center value, and the left middle value.   if x=1 and y=1, then i would need to grab all 8 other values.    the 2D array may vary in size and shape,  so the solution can't rely on a 3x3.

how would I get the new array with the valid values?

thanks

Comment: If you had to write some code to do this, where do you think you might start? It's OK to try *something* even if you're not sure it is the right thing. You can even start by just writing the definition of a function to do this, before you know what to put in that function.

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs the following input:

- What's the `x` and `y` coordinate for which you need to find neighbors
- What is the definition of neighbor
- What is in the matrix

### Getting a value from the matrix

To get an `(x, y)` coordinate, I propose this function:

```
// Returns `undefined` for out-of-bound coordinates
const getFromMatrix = m => ([x, y]) => (m[y] || [])[x];
```

This takes a small shortcut: it returns `undefined` for values that are out of bounds. Therefore, it will only work if your matrix does not contain any `undefined` values.

### Defining the neighbors

Defining the neighbors can be done by an array of *delta* `x` and `y` values:

```
// [ [ dX, dY ] ]
const neighborDirs = [
  [ -1, -1 ], [  0, -1 ], [ 1, -1 ],
  [ -1,  0 ],             [ 1,  0 ],
  [ -1,  1 ], [  0,  1 ], [ 1,  1 ]
];
```

This data format makes it easy to loop over all neighbors. If you don't want the diagonal neighbors, you remove the top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right delta pairs from the constant.

### Chaining it all together

The last step is to go from:

1. Neighboring directions, to
2. Values in the matrix, to
3. Only the valid values that are not out of bounds

In code:

```
// Assumes matrix does not contain `undefined` values
const getNeighbors = (x, y, n, m) => n
  // From deltas to coordinates
  .map(([dX, dY]) => [ x + dX, y + dY ])
  // From coordinates to values
  .map(getFromMatrix(m))
  // Filter out-of-bounds
  .filter(v => v !== undefined)
```

### Running example

Here's a running snippet with your example data:

```js
const matrix = [
   [0,1,2],
   [2,0,0],
   [1,0,2]
];

// [ dX, dY ]
const neighborDirs = [
  [ -1, -1 ], [  0, -1 ], [ 1, -1 ],
  [ -1,  0 ],             [ 1,  0 ],
  [ -1,  1 ], [  0,  1 ], [ 1,  1 ]
];

// Returns `undefined` for out-of-bound coordinates
const getFromMatrix = m => ([x, y]) => (m[y] || [])[x];

// Assumes matrix does not contain `undefined` values
const getNeighbors = (x, y, n, m) => n
  // From deltas to coordinates
  .map(([dX, dY]) => [ x + dX, y + dY ])
  // From coordinates to values
  .map(getFromMatrix(m))
  // Filter out-of-bounds
  .filter(v => v !== undefined)


// 1, 2, 0
console.log(
  "(0,0) =>", 
  JSON.stringify(
    getNeighbors(0, 0, neighborDirs, matrix)
  )
);

// 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2
console.log(
  "(1,1) =>", 
  JSON.stringify(
    getNeighbors(1, 1, neighborDirs, matrix)
  )
);
```

Comment: I'm a few years late but I just ran across this question. What does `const getFromMatrix = m => ([x, y]) => (m[y] || [])[x];` do? I don't understand the second part.

Comment: In a 2d-array `m`, you use `m[y][x]` to access a single cell. When, for example, you're trying to get the top neighbor of a cell that's already on the top row, `m[-1]` would return `undefined`. Writing `undefined[x]` will throw an error. The code above is a shorter way of writing `if (m[y]) return m[y][x]; else return undefined`. How it works: the code between `(..)` is executed first. `m[y]` returns undefined, which means the part right of the `||` is evaluated and returned: a new empty array. Then, `[][x]` is evaluated, which returns `undefined` (indicating the cell is out of bounds).